# Finding two rationals that satisfy an equation

Tags: real-analysis

So the homework question goes as follows:

> Find rational numbers such that $ \sqrt[3]{7+5\sqrt{2}}=\alpha+\beta\sqrt{2}$

The homework only asks for one pair of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and it is almost trivial to find the solution $\alpha=\beta = 1$

Solution:

$\sqrt[3]{7+5\sqrt{2}}=\alpha+\beta\sqrt{2}$

$7+5\sqrt{2}=(\alpha+\beta\sqrt{2})^3$

$7+5\sqrt{2}=\alpha^3+6\beta^2\alpha +\sqrt{2}(3 \alpha^2 \beta +2\beta^3)$

By identification of coefficients:

$7=\alpha^3+6\beta^2\alpha \space and \space 5=3 \alpha^2 \beta +2\beta^3$

So I just "saw" that $\alpha=\beta = 1$ is a solution

My question is, how do we find other solutions?

Thank you!

Comment: If you have a possibly different solution, $z = \alpha + \beta\sqrt{2}$ with $(\alpha,\beta) \neq (1,1)$, then $\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta\sqrt{2}}{1+\sqrt{2}}\right)^3 = \left((2\beta-\alpha) + (\alpha-\beta)\sqrt{2}\right)^3 = 1$.

Comment: Another way to see uniqueness is to use the fact that $x \mapsto x^3$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: Aren’t you looking for cube roots of $7+5\sqrt2$? But you probably know already that any two cube roots of a number are related by a factor $(-1\pm\sqrt{-3})/2$. So the other cube roots are not of the desired form.

Comment: You may want to look at [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/491464/finding-rational-numbers/491489#491489).

Comment: I find it interesting that this exact problem appears again. I wonder what's the source

Answer (score 0):

The real solutions of a cube root of a positive number are positive numbers, and if you have two positive real-valued solutions then they must be equal. So if $\alpha_1 + \beta_1 \sqrt{2} = \alpha_2 + \beta_2 \sqrt{2}$ are two different solutions where all $\alpha_i, \beta_i$ are rational then you will be able to solve for $\sqrt{2}$ as a rational number, which is impossible. So there is only at most one solution.